# Adding Auto Increment to a column without rebuilding the table

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to add Auto Increment to an existing column without having mysql rebuild the entire table?

**Edit** - I am doing an `ALTER`, but it takes ages and ages, because mysql rebuilds the entire table structure. What this question is about is whether there is a way to speedup this process - after all, the logical operation of adding "auto increment" shouldn't have to touch any table data, it's just how mysql is implemented.

Answer (score -1):

```
ALTER TABLE [table] ADD [columname] INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```

Alternatively you could set the start number of the `AUTO_INCREMENT`

```
ALTER TABLE [table] AUTO_INCREMENT = [start]
```

Comment: mysql does rebuild the entire table when you ALTER (this operation takes a LONG time for large tables). I was looking for some _way_ to make mysql do this in O(1) (read: really fast, or at least o(n)).